# RadGrid with arbitray number of Master-Detail levels

Tags: radgrid

Is it possible to create a hierarchical grid dynamically, with an arbitrary number of Master-Detail levels ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto generated hierarchy. It is working with DataSets and it is out of the box functionality for the radgrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateHierarchy="true">       
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   RadGrid1.DataSource = MyDataSet;           
}
```

Check [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/autogeneratedhierarchy/defaultcs.aspx) link which demonstrates that functionality.